# How to use data-binding with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

I'm trying to follow data-binding example from official google doc https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

except that I'm trying to apply data-biding to a fragment, not an activity.

the error I'm currently getting when compiling is

`Error:(37, 27) No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{marsdata.martianSols}.`

`onCreate` for fragment looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MartianDataBinding binding = MartianDataBinding.inflate(getActivity().getLayoutInflater());
    binding.setMarsdata(this);
}
```

`onCreateView` for fragment looks like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.martian_data, container, false);
}
```

and parts of my layout file for fragment looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="marsdata"
            type="uk.co.darkruby.app.myapp.MarsDataProvider" />
    </data>
...

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{marsdata.martianSols}"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

my suspicion is that `MartianDataBinding` doesn't know which layout file it's supposed to be bound with - hence the error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 460, accepted):

The data binding implementation must be in the `onCreateView` method of the fragment, delete any data Binding that exist in your `OnCreate` method,
your `onCreateView` should look like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MartianDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.martian_data, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    //here data must be an instance of the class MarsDataProvider
    binding.setMarsdata(data);
    return view;
}
```

Smart way to bind the fragment View using `abastract` `generics` classes : `BindingFragment.kt`

```
        abstract class BindingFragment<T : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {
            protected lateinit var binding: T

            abstract fun getViewBinding(): T

            override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
                binding = getViewBinding()
                return binding.root
            }
        }
```

override the function in your `Fragment class`:

```
        class YourFragment: BindingFragment<YourFragmentFragBinding>(){

        override fun getViewBinding() = YourFragmentFragBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
                
                // write here your view logics 
                }

        }
```

Comment: I had to add the call to super to have my Binding class generate.

Comment: if you have do same thing with kotlin please refer https://androidteachers.com/kotlin-for-android/manage-fragment-data-binding-kotlin/

Comment: how to access views like toolbar, textviews .. etc?

Comment: I struggles with this issue for hours. The problem was I returned the wrong view. +1

Comment: what is  DataType  of "data" ?

Comment: `View view = binding.getRoot();`

I've been stuck on this for so long that I'm legitimately pretty upset that I couldn't find any documentation about it on developer.android.com... Solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: MartianDataBinding cannot resolve getting this error , how can I solve

Comment: If you're using LiveData and ViewModel, make sure to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932633/1015595).

Comment: what is setMarsdata() ? i think here we use setViewModel()??

Comment: This causes an error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node**

Comment: `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` also needs to be called to be able to update the UI. Otherwise, the UI changes will not be visible. At least in my case when using LiveData

Comment: also don't forget to set `binding.viewHolder = yourViewModel` else data will be missing

Answer (score 102):

You are actually encouraged to use the `inflate` method of your generated Binding and not the DataBindingUtil:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MainFragmentBinding binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    //set variables in Binding
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

(MainFragmentBinding is automatically generated for R.layout.main_fragment)

[Docs for DataBindingUtil.inflate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)):

> Use this version only if layoutId is unknown in advance. Otherwise, use the generated Binding's inflate method to ensure type-safe inflation.

Comment: Unfortunately this is killing me with the `cannot be resolved to a type` error on build. It is not reliable in my opinion. If I go first with `DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);` and then change it to `FragmentCameraBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);`, it works, but after rebuild it gives the error again.

Comment: Works great. Actually no need to specify layout res id (which i was wondering before) as it automatically picks from the generated binding file.

Comment: where do you set the fragment layout id (eg. R.layout.fragment_) in this example?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. the layout generated binding is encouraged to be used, instead of `DataBindingUtil.inflate`

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran The layout id is implied through the use of the `MainFragmentBinding` class. That class is generated from the layout file so the desired layout is automatically applied.

Comment: However, if you look at the generated class they have marked the generated overload inflate function as deprecated and pointing to DataBindingUtil.inflate().


/**
   * This method receives DataBindingComponent instance as type Object instead of
   * type DataBindingComponent to avoid causing too many compilation errors if
   * compilation fails for another reason.
   * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116541301
   * @Deprecated Use DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_name, root, attachToRoot, component)
   */

Answer (score 33):

If you are using **ViewModel** and **LiveData** This is the sufficient syntax

**Kotlin Syntax:**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return MartianDataBinding.inflate(
        inflater,
        container,
        false
    ).apply {
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        vm = viewModel    // Attach your view model here
    }.root
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Just as most have said, but dont forget to set **LifeCycleOwner** 
**Sample in Java**
i.e

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    BindingClass binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    ModelClass model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ViewModelClass.class);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(getActivity());
    binding.setViewmodelclass(model);

    //Your codes here

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this in Android DataBinding

```
FragmentMainBinding binding;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        View rootView = binding.getRoot();
        initInstances(savedInstanceState);
        return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Kotlin syntax:**

```
lateinit var binding: MartianDataBinding
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.martian_data, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One can simply retrieve view object as mentioned below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.layout_file, container, false).getRoot();

return view;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

A complete example in data binding Fragments

FragmentMyProgramsBinding  is binding class generated for res/layout/fragment_my_programs

```
public class MyPrograms extends Fragment {
    FragmentMyProgramsBinding fragmentMyProgramsBinding;

    public MyPrograms() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FragmentMyProgramsBinding    fragmentMyProgramsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R
                .layout.fragment_my_programs, container, false);
        return fragmentMyProgramsBinding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

working in my code.

```
private FragmentSampleBinding dataBiding;
private SampleListAdapter mAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    dataBiding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_sample, null, false);
    return mView = dataBiding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can do it in kotlin:

```
//Pass the layout as parameter to the fragment constructor    
class SecondFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_second) {

    private var _binding: FragmentSecondBinding? = null
    private val binding  get() = _binding!!

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _binding = FragmentSecondBinding.bind(view)  //if the view is already inflated then we can just bind it to view binding.

    }

    //Note: Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class
    // instance in the fragment's onDestroyView() method.
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "On destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

You can access the view elements from your layouts like:

```
binding.tvName.text = "Messi"
```

where tvName is the id of the view element.

Answer (score 3):

I have been finding Answer for my application and here is the answer for Kotlin Language.

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: FragmentForgetPasswordBinding

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding=DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_forget_password,container,false)
    
    val viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this).get(ForgetPasswordViewModel::class.java)
    binding.recoveryViewModel=viewModel
    viewModel.forgetPasswordInterface=this
    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin**

```
         override fun onCreateView(
                 inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                 savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View? 
    { 
                 val binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)      
               return  binding.root;
            

}
```

where **FragmentFirstBinding** is Automatic generated by android studio using view binding. In my code fragment name is **FirstFragment**.

First, you need to add this line to your build.Gradle(app module) file.

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another example in Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate< MartianDataBinding >(
                    inflater,
                    R.layout.bla,
                    container,
                    false
            )

    binding.modelName = // ..

    return binding.root
}
```

Note that the name "MartianDataBinding" depends on the name of the layout file. If the file is named "martian_data" then the correct name would be MartianDataBinding.

Answer (score 2):

Very helpful blog about Databinding :
https://link.medium.com/HQY2VizKO1

```
class FragmentBinding<out T : ViewDataBinding>(
    @LayoutRes private val resId: Int
) : ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, T> {

    private var binding: T? = null

    override operator fun getValue(
        thisRef: Fragment,
        property: KProperty<*>
    ): T = binding ?: createBinding(thisRef).also { binding = it }

    private fun createBinding(
        activity: Fragment
    ): T = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(activity.context),resId,null,true)
}
```

Declare binding val like this in Fragment :

```
private val binding by FragmentBinding<FragmentLoginBinding>(R.layout.fragment_login)
```

Don't forget to write this in fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone says about `inflate()`, but what if we want to use it in `onViewCreated()`?

You can use **`bind(view)`** method of concrete binding class to get `ViewDataBinding` instance for the `view`.

Usually we write BaseFragment something like this (simplified):

```
// BaseFragment.kt
abstract fun layoutId(): Int

override fun onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState) = 
    inflater.inflate(layoutId(), container, false)
```

And use it in child fragment.

```
// ConcreteFragment.kt
override fun layoutId() = R.layout.fragment_concrete

override fun onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) {
    val binding = FragmentConcreteBinding.bind(view)
    // or
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.bind<FragmentConcreteBinding>(view)
}
```

If all Fragments uses data binding, you can even make it simpler using type parameter.

```
abstract class BaseFragment<B: ViewDataBinding> : Fragment() {
    abstract fun onViewCreated(binding: B, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        onViewCreated(DataBindingUtil.bind<B>(view)!!, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

I don't know it's okay to assert non-null there, but.. you get the idea. If you want it to be nullable, you can do it.

Comment: How to bind viewModel when using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way in Kotlin;

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val binding = FragmentHomeBinding.bind(view)
    // todo 
    }
```