# RuntimeException when dynamically replacing a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have been trying to replace a fragment dynamically in my app , but I keep getting a RuntimeException when doing so , as it can't find the container ID it is supposed to add the fragment to . I have tried every single solution I found on similar threads , from doing a clean build to using a ChildFragmentManager but still , I have the same error . 
The weirdest thing is that when I specify no container in the onCreate , everything goes fine but as soon as a container is specified , the app crashes . Here is the code and the stack trace :

Stack Trace :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.onceuponatime, PID: 23668
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.onceuponatime/com.example.user.onceuponatime.activity.AuthentificationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d007f (com.example.user.onceuponatime:id/fragment_container) for fragment SignInFragment{42d6c688 #0 id=0x7f0d007f signinfragment}
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d007f (com.example.user.onceuponatime:id/fragment_container) for fragment SignInFragment{42d6c688 #0 id=0x7f0d007f signinfragment}
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AuthentificationActivity :

```
public class AuthentificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignInFragment.SignInFragmentCallBack
        ,SignUpFragment.SignUpFragmentCallBack{

    public static final String SIGNINFRAGMENT_TAG = "signinfragment";
    public static final String SIGNUPFRAGMENT_TAG = "signupfragment";

    public static final int SIGNIN_FRAGMENT_ID = 846464;
    public static final int SIGNUP_FRAGMENT_ID = 125478;
    public static final int LOST_PWD_FRAGMENT_ID = 85546;

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private SignInFragment mSignInFragment;
    private SignUpFragment mSignUpFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentification);


        mSignInFragment = SignInFragment.getInstance();

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,mSignInFragment,SIGNINFRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentSwapRequested(int FragmentId) {

        mFragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fgTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch(FragmentId) {
            case SIGNUP_FRAGMENT_ID:
                if(!isFinishing()) {
                    mSignUpFragment = (SignUpFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SIGNUPFRAGMENT_TAG);
                    if (mSignUpFragment == null) {
                        mSignUpFragment = SignUpFragment.getInstance();
                        fgTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSignUpFragment, SIGNUPFRAGMENT_TAG);
                    } else {
                        fgTransaction.show(mSignUpFragment);
                    }
                    fgTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fgTransaction.commit();
                }
                break;
            case LOST_PWD_FRAGMENT_ID:
                break;


        }



    }
}
```

SignInFragment :

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment {
    FragmentSignInBinding signInBinding;

    private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinatorLayout;
    private EditText mEmailEdit,mPasswordEdit;
    private Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp,btnLostPwd;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private SignInFragmentCallBack mCallBack;



    public interface SignInFragmentCallBack {
        void onFragmentSwapRequested(int FragmentId);
    }

    public SignInFragment() {}


    public static SignInFragment getInstance() {
        return new SignInFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mCallBack = (SignInFragmentCallBack) context;
        } catch(ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implements SignInCallaback");
        }
        Toast.makeText(context,mCallBack.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        signInBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_sign_in);
        mEmailEdit = signInBinding.emailSignin;
        mPasswordEdit = signInBinding.passwordSignin;
        mProgressBar = signInBinding.progressBarSignIn;
        btnSignIn = signInBinding.signInButton;
        btnSignUp = signInBinding.signUpButton;
        btnLostPwd = signInBinding.passwordReset;
        mCoordinatorLayout = signInBinding.coordinatorSignin;



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signInAction();
            }
        });

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCallBack instanceof SignInFragmentCallBack)
                mCallBack.onFragmentSwapRequested(AuthentificationActivity.SIGNUP_FRAGMENT_ID);
            }
        });

        btnLostPwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCallBack instanceof SignInFragmentCallBack)
                mCallBack.onFragmentSwapRequested(AuthentificationActivity.LOST_PWD_FRAGMENT_ID);
            }
        });


    }

    private void signInAction() {
        String email = mEmailEdit.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = mPasswordEdit.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,getString(R.string.no_email_entered),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,getString(R.string.no_password_entered),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,getString(R.string.login_success),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,getString(R.string.login_failed),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

activity_authentification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_authentification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.onceuponatime.activity.AuthentificationActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT :** I tried checking the R.java to see if the Id's were messed up but it seems like everything is fine , with the fragment_container id clearly exisisting . Also tried cleaning the project but as I expected , this didn't change anything . I tried replacing add with replace() but still , same error , except when I use android.R.id.container as the container . I am using data binding , maybe it's the cause of the conflict ?

**EDIT2 :** I have created a new project where I did the same transaction but with a simple fragment displaying a simple TextView , and everything seems to work fine , no crash in sight . So I tried deleting the ambiguous items in my fragment such as the callback , but I still get the same mistake . DataBinding doesn't seem to be the issue since I tried without it and still get the same stack trace .

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way... "authentication", not "authentification"

Comment: :) The rest of the variables are english... Anyways.. `fragment_container` definitely exists, and you only use it three spots, but the error comes from an `onStart` of an Activity, which it's not clear where

Comment: Yes that's what the stack trace is showing but i don't even override the onStart() .I tried running it on 2 different devices but the bug is code related and not device related

Comment: The crash only happens when you swap?

Comment: If i specify the container in the add() method , the app doesn't even start . It crashes immediately , if i specify no container ID except in the replace() method , it crashes when I swap !

Comment: Worth checking out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16843590/2308683

Comment: Already checked this thread , most of the answers did not work out for me , or were not suited to my case . I will read it again and see if i missed something

Comment: Check that one answer I linked to. Open up the `R.java` file and see if your id's are messed up. Even if not, cleaning the app, or making sure you have no other `fragment_container` ID in another layout file.

Comment: Just checked the R file again but everything seems right . Tried cleaning the project , but same mistake. I'm using data binding , maybe it's causing the errors ?

Comment: I just realized you had data-binding and you are doing it wrong in a Fragment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706399/how-to-use-data-binding-with-fragment#34719627

Comment: Thank you! The problem was coming from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to bind the `signInFragment` UI to its behavior in the `onCreate` method, but this method is called before `onCreateView` as you can see on the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

If you move the content of your `onCreate` method in your `onCreateView`, or any method called afterward you won't have this crash anymore.

Comment: Thank you ! This has fixed my main issue , however , when I click on the button which is supposed to show the SignUpFragment , I get the IllegalStateArgument exception , even though I moved most of the critical code to the onActivityCreated() . Any hints ? I'm thinking of just getting rid of the DataBinding since it has caused only problems so far.