# Data Binding in Android

Tags: android, data-binding

I know this is not something new to ask but as I am in need to add data binding in java(generated) package and I haven't used it before in any of my previous projects so what I can see on the internet is to add this to my app-level build.gradle file inside the android.

```
      dataBinding {
      enabled = true
      }
```

but it is not working and the error what I am getting is

```
[databinding] {"msg":"No class attribute for \u0027view\u0027 node","file":"C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\Astrotell Project\\AstrotellUserApp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_resetpassword.xml","pos":[]}
```

I do not understand the meaning of this and also my fragment_resetoassword is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.Resetpassword">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_fg_reset_"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl_fg_reset_backarrowLayout">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_fg_reset_back"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/back_black"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_fg_resrt_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_logo"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange2"/>
        <com.kookyapps.astrotelluserapp.CustomViews.PoppinsBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fg_reset_resetText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_fg_resrt_logo"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:text="@string/resetPasswordTitle"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack2"/>
        <com.kookyapps.astrotelluserapp.CustomViews.PopinsRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fg_reset_enterText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_fg_reset_resetText"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/enterdetails"
            android:textColor="@color/grey2" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_fg_reset_newpassLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_fg_reset_enterText">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_fg_reset_newpass"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lock_deselect"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/et_fg_reset_newpass"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_fg_reset_newpass"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/newpass"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/iv_fg_reset_eye"
                android:src="@drawable/eye_deselect"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/v_fg_reset_newpass"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_fg_reset_newpassLayout"/>




        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_fg_reset_confirmpassLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_fg_reset_newpassLayout">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_fg_reset_confirmpass"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lock_deselect"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/et_fg_reset_confirmpass"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_fg_reset_confirmpass"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/confirmpass"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/iv_fg_reset_eye_confirmpass"
                android:src="@drawable/eye_deselect"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/v_fg_reset_confirmpass"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_fg_reset_confirmpassLayout"/>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_fg_reset_resetbtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_fg_reset_confirmpassLayout">
            <com.kookyapps.astrotelluserapp.CustomViews.PopinsRegularTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_fg_reset_resetPassText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/reset"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I need to import data binding in my fragment class but I don't have any idea how will I do it, I have searched on  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding  and https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago/issues/28 there is one more I searched and found [How to use data-binding with Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706399/how-to-use-data-binding-with-fragment)  but in my case, if I write this class It does not find this library.
So I have tried these yet I didn't find any solution to resolve my problem if someone could genuinely help me then I would be grateful to him.

Comment: did you convert this XML layout manually or using the built-in converter? Converter adds the `<layout>` tags and builds the class for you, you may also need to clean and rebuild your project before it's accessible.

Comment: that <layout> tag has been added by the converter ???
in my case, I have made that tag clean and rebuilt I have done many time . 
could you please let me know in detail if you are getting where am I wrong

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong view tag i.e view use View instead view , your problem will resolve.

Comment: I admit it should be View , I am correcting it and lets see what happens

Comment: Hopefully, it will work because I did not find any issue in your binding code.